# How can i redirect to another page by click on hyperlink in Html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a navigation bar , 
current url : **www.domain.com/what-is-your-fb-username-?/**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Shuboy2014</a>
         </div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="active"><a href='delete/'>Delete</a></li>
           <li class="active"><a href="edit/">Update</a></li>
           <li class="active"><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
```

When I click on logout option on the navigational bar it redirects to **www.domain.com/what-is-your-fb-username-?/logout** and I want to go to **www.domain.com/logout** .

How can I do this? Any helpful suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change the href url of logout:

From: `<li class="active"><a href="logout">Logout</a></li>`

to: `<li class="active"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Shuboy2014</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href='delete/'>Delete</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="edit/">Update</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid these kinds of errors is to specify the full path in (all) your links - i.e. http://www.domain.com/folder/page.html.

You will find that getting into this habit will avoid errors, especially if you refer to external links.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Simply put a `/` at the front of the href, eg `/logout`

Having `/` in the front makes it a [path-absolute url](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#syntax-url-path-absolute) and will be used as the full path part to the current domain.

> A path-absolute URL must be "/" followed by a path-relative URL.

You can also use the `<base>` tag to set the base URL that relative paths will use to make the full url. So if base was `http://stackoverflow.com/` and the current page is at `http://stackoverflow.com/assets` all relative urls would start with `http://stackoverflow.com/` and not `http://stackoverflow.com/assests`

```js
console.log("Document location:", document.location.href );
console.log("anchor href: ",document.querySelector("a").href);
```

```html
<base href="http://stacksnippets.net/">
<a href="assets/test.html">Relative of &lt;base&gt;</a>
```